# R: Find position of an element inside a vector

Tags: r, while-loop

I have this vector with names:

```
students <- c("Mykola", "Li", "Daniel", "Jan", "Lukas")
```

I would like to find a random order, where "Jan" is after "Li", but not necessarily immediately after.
My current thought was that a while() loop is drawing random samples again and again as long as the vector position of Jan is smaller than the position of Li. But I do not know how to find out the vector position.

My code so far:

```
students <- c("Mykola", "Li", "Daniel", "Jan", "Lukas")
order <- function()
{
  draw <- sample(students, 5, replace = FALSE)
  print(draw)
  while("vector position Jan" < "vector position Li")
  {
    draw
    print(draw)
  }
}
print(draw)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `which` to get the position :

```
random_order <- function(students)
{
  positon_jan = 0
  positon_li = Inf
  while(positon_jan < positon_li)
  {
    draw <- sample(students, 5)
    positon_jan <- which(draw == 'Jan')
    positon_li <- which(draw == 'Li')
  }
  return(draw)
}
random_order(students)
#[1] "Li"     "Jan"    "Daniel" "Mykola" "Lukas" 
random_order(students)
#[1] "Lukas"  "Daniel" "Mykola" "Li"     "Jan"   
random_order(students)
#[1] "Li"     "Daniel" "Mykola" "Lukas"  "Jan"
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is the position of jan and Li at the beginning equal to "0" and "Inf"?

Comment: That is to initialise the value such as the condition is `TRUE` for the first time. `0 < Inf` gives `TRUE`, you can also use 1 and 2 since `1 < 2` is `TRUE` as well.